# How do I define constants that must be overridden inside an interface?

Tags: java, interface, constants, java-7

To create kits that players can choose, I have made an interface:

```
public interface Kit {}
```

And I have implemented it for each kit:

```
public class Ninja implements Kit {}
```

Now, I want to set some constants related to the class, not the instance.
I want these to be static across all implementations of the interface, and I want each implementation to override them.

Try #1:

```
public interface Kit {
    String DISPLAY_NAME;
    // The blank final field DISPLAY_NAME may not have been initialized
}
```

Try #2:

```
public interface Kit {  
    static String getDisplayName();
    // Illegal modifier for the interface method getDisplayName; only public & abstract are permitted
}
```

Comment: So you want all classes to have a unique name but make sure that all implementations have the `String getName()` method? To me it sounds more like the case for an abstract class than an interface.

Comment: @Emz What do you mean by _implementations_?

Comment: When you do `Ninja a = new Ninja (); Ninja b = new Ninja ();` do you want `a` and `b` to be able to have different values? Of their `name` field, while still making sure they have name fields?

Comment: @Emz No, because these fields should be constants related to the class, not the instance.

Answer (score 2):

An interface can not hold data the way a class can hold a field. If you do not want your `Kit` to be instantiated, you most likely want an abstract class. See them as an interface that can have some implementation and fields.

**Note, please read for further clarfication:** [Read More](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/interface-vs-abstract-class/)

So what you want in this to have an abstract class in the background, not an interface. Now how does that look?

```
public abstract class Kit {
    protected final String name = "Foo";

    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Here we have our Kit, every class implementing `Kit` will have access to the `name` field. I might recommend putting it in caps if it is supposed to be a constant. It might be best with a static property as well. More of that can be read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

To illustrate I've made two classes inherit from our `abstract class Kit`. `Ninja` and `Test`.

```
public class Ninja extends Kit {
}
```

This class purpose is just to check if `name` really has the value of `Foo` or not.

Then we need our actual test class as well.

```
public class Test extends Kit {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Test ninja = new Test ();
        System.out.println(ninja.getName());    // foo
        Ninja ninja2 = new Ninja ();
        System.out.println(ninja2.getName());   // foo
    } 
}
```

They are both of different types, `Test` resp. `Ninja` but they both have the value of `foo` in their `name` field. It will be true for every class that inherits from `Kit`.

If **must be overriden** is a requirement then I suggest to add a `constructor` of `Kit` to force the user to add data from the base class.

```
public abstract class Kit {
    protected String name;

    public Kit (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Now every class that inherits from `Kit` must invoke `super (String)`, meaning the `name` field will be set for every object. It can be different from `class A extends Kit` and `class B extends Kit`. Is that what you searched for?

If so, then implementing `class A` and `class B` will look along these lines.

```
class A extends Kit {
    public A (String name) {
        super (name);
    }
}
```

And for `B` it will be the following.

```
class B extends Kit {
    public B (String name) {
        super (name);
    }
}
```

Now they are different classes, can hold different fields and methods, but they both need to set the `name` field of the base class: `Kit`.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods aren't virtual, which means you can't define an abstract static method on an interface and expect it to be overridden and called at the subclass level like:

```
// Doesn't even compile!
public interface Kit {
  static String name();
}

public class Ninja implements Kit {
  @Override public static name() { return "Ninja"; }
}
```

If you need to define values as runtime constants in the scope of a given class (for example all Ninja instances must return `"NINJA"`), you may hardcode the name at the class level in a regular, non-static, virtual method, or otherwise use something injection friendly like

```
public class KitTranslator {
  public void translate(Kit kit) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

You can then ensure there exists only one `KitTranslator` in your application.

I strongly discourage to use any implementation involving `static`, because it will mess with the initialization order of your application sooner or later, and because `static` fields propagates indefinetly until the userspace. Also, since static is not virtual at any level, you'll have troubles when you need to grow your code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to require subclasses to contain some particular static fields

```
/**
 * subclass MUST define static field "KIT_NAME" !!!!
 */
public interface Kit

---

public class Ninja implements Kit

    public static final String KIT_NAME = "Ninja"
```

This requirement cannot be enforced by the compiler. It's a convention that the programmer must follow. That's not really a big problem.

At runtime, use reflection to read the field from the subclass.

---

Another, fancier way, is by using annotation

```
@KitInfo(name="Ninja")
public class Ninja implements Kit
```

This is a little better than static fields. You can even write a preprocessor to enforce that `@KitInfo` must be annotated for any subclass of Kit. (What can't be done by preprocessor?:)

---

Now, for the fun of it, let's solve it by generics

```
public interface Kit<I extends Kit.Info>
{
    public interface Info
    {
        String name();
    }
}

public class Ninja implements Kit<Ninja.Info>
{
    public static class Info implements Kit.Info
    { 
        public String name(){ return "Ninja"; }
    }
}
```

At runtime, given a subclass of Kit, we can use reflection to get the concrete type of `I`.